# I have a recursively defined function, and another function involving powers of a matrix. How can I show that they are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

The problem is

> Let $A$ be the $n \times n$ adjacency matrix of a graph $G=(V,E)$ on $n$ vertices, i.e. $A=(a_{ij})$ and 
>   $$a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
> 1 & ij\in E  \\ 0 & ij\notin E
> \end{cases}$$ Show that the $i,j$ entry of $A^k$ is the number of $i-j$ walks in $G$ that use exactly $k$ edges.

I'm *almost* done but I don't quite believe my solution. Here's what I have.

> Let $w_k(i,j)$ be the number of $i-j$ walks of length $k$. Clearly, $$w_{1}(i,j)=\begin{cases}
> 1 & ij\in E  \\ 0 & ij\notin E
> \end{cases}$$
>   The number of $i-j$ walks of length $k$ equal to the number of walks of length $k-1$ from $i$ to a vertex in $N(j)$ where $N(j)$ is the set of vertices adjacent to $j$, so we have $$w_k(i,j)=\sum_{x \in N(j)}w_{k-1}(i,x)$$
>   Now,, $[A^k]_{ij}=[A^{k-1}A]_{ij}=[A^{k-1}]_i^T [A]_j$, where the subscripts denote columns of the matrix in brackets (since $A$ is symmetric and hence powers thereof are also symmetric). We can write this as $$[A^k]_{ij}=\sum_{l=1}^n[A^{k-1}]_{il}[A]_{lj}$$
>
> And by the definition of $A$, this is equivalent to $$[A^k]_{ij}=\sum_{x\in N(j)}[A^{k-1}]_{ix}$$

Obviously these recursive definitions look very similar and I can't decide if I am done or not. How can I show that these are in fact are the exact same function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you’ve not really made it clear. What you want to do is show by inductionn on $k$ that $w_k(i,j)=[A^k]_{ij}$ for all $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. This is clearly the case for $k=1$. If $k>1$, and if it holds for $k-1$, then

$$\begin{align*}
w_k(i,j)&=\sum_{\ell\in N(j)}w_{k-1}(i,\ell)\\
&=\sum_{\ell\in N(j)}[A^{k-1}]_{i\ell}&\text{induction hypothesis}\\
&=\sum_{\ell=1}^n[A^{k-1}]_{i\ell}[A]_{\ell j}&\text{since }[A]_{\ell j}=\begin{cases}1,&\ell\in N(j)\\0,&\ell\notin N(j)\end{cases}\\
&=[A^k]_{ij}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and we’re home free.

Comment: right, I did write that part. My question is more about the implicit assertion that $A^l=w_l$, i.e. raising $A$ to a power is the same as applying $w$ $l$ times.

Comment: @crf: Now that I look more closely, I see quite a bit more that you really ought to have said (and that I mentally filled in without realizing that I was doing so). Give me a few minutes to expand my answer.

Comment: @crf: See how this version looks.

Comment: Awesome. I was thinking that maybe there was some argument that could me made that matrix multiplication is like applying the same function over and over again and so those are actually the same thing, but I don't know if that works. This works perfectly though.

Comment: @crf: I suspect (without having thought it through) that anything along those lines would in the end come down to this or something very similar anyway.